# Создать глобальную переменную

Tags: php

как мне известно, переменные в php с формы на форму отправляются формой method=post, =get или через адресную строку как Get переменную... можно ли создать переменную для php-файла, которая будет сохраняться в документе без <form>...</form>??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам помогут сессии. Почитайте про глобальные массивы в частности про $_SESSION

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)